# How to retrieve data for a períod of time (-10 months) in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to count the number of transactions in the last 10 months. How do i get this with Entity Framework?

I tried to do this code:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var Model = db.Transactions
                  .Where(u => u.TransactionsDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-10))
                  .Count();

    Response.Write(Model);
    return null;
}
```

with that code i have this error page:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ can't translate that method call into a SQL expression.  But you don't need it to, you can just store the value from that method call and pass the value to LINQ:

```
var someValue = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-10);
var model = db.Transactions.Where(u => u.TransactionsDate > someValue).Count();
```

---

Side note... This is *very wrong*:

```
Response.Write(model);
return null;
```

Your method returns an `ActionResult`, so return an `ActionResult`.  What should that result be?  For example, if you're calling this from AJAX and expecting JSON data, return that as your result:

```
return Json(model);
```

Or perhaps this action needs to return a *view* to render a page in the browser?:

```
return View(model);
```

You *almost never* write directly to the response, and a method which *always* returns `null` is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

You could define your "ten months ago" like:

```
DateTime tenMonthsAgo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-10);
```

thus:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static List<DateTime> getDates()
    {
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2018,1,1);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2018,5,1);
        DateTime d3 = new DateTime(2018,12,1);

        List<DateTime> db = new List<DateTime>();

        db.Add(d1);
        db.Add(d2);
        db.Add(d3);

        return db;      
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var model = getDates();     
        DateTime tenMonthsAgo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-10);      

        var query = model.Where(dates => dates.Month > tenMonthsAgo.Month);

        foreach (var q in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("res: " + q); 
             //res:5/1/2018 12:00:00 AM
             //res:12/1/2018 12:00:00 AM
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That `.Where()` logic is going to fail as soon as the data rolls over into a new year.